# Google Sheets - Find and Replace Cell Value on Import

Tags: if-statement, replace, find

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Of3VK4EXYM1D6xBWp_0FoeoUoMvMmaOmBnzAO1pieU/edit?usp=sharing

**Goal:** Replace "Americas Liner" with "Americas" in "Position List!A2:A" automatically.

**Script didn't work:** I tried running a script that replaced the text but since all of my text is generated from a formula in cell A1 it broke my import.  You cant edit a cell that is being generated from an importrange.

**IF formula didn't work:** I also tried replacing the text on import:

```
=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IMPORTRANGE("key","MasterList!A1:A")="","",IF(IMPORTRANGE("key", "MasterList!A1:A")="Americas Liner","Americas",""))),IMPORTRANGE("key", "MasterList!B1:V")},"Select * where Col10 contains 'Position List' ")
```

This is because column A has more results than just "Americas" and "Americas Liner". You can't "do nothing" IF false and I would have to return something other than its current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just pasted the data into B1, and in A:A, =IF(B2="bad name","good name","B2") and just hide B:B.  It creates an extra column but I worked around that.